# Isn't defining the unit of length in terms of the speed of light kind of faulty?

Tags: measurements, metrology

well I was reading Halliday and it defined the standard of length as follows

"The standard of length, which corresponds to exactly 1.0 meters, is the distance travelled by light in a vacuum during a certain fraction of a second"

well light has certain speed, speed is derived from length and time, and to measure something you need its units.

now according to Halliday the standard of a meter is defined by some certain length it travels in a fraction of time. Lets assume that we know the definition of time

let speed of light be c

c=3*10^8 m/s

which means every second that passes, light travels a distance of 3*10^8 meters

and according to Halliday to define the standard of meters light travels certain distance in some certain time to give 1.0 meter

so I am defining meter with the use speed of light and at the same time, I am defining the speed of light (speed in general too) with the use of meter

which implies that to define one we basically need the other, ending with having no independent definition of either of things

which makes me think, isn't this kind of a circular logic, like I am using one definition(definition of meter)  to define something new(definition of unit speed), and I am using this new definition(definition of unit speed) to define the old thing(definition of meter)

can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 7):

The [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (SI) defines practical ways for laboratories to create their own implementations of reference units. Since 2019 or so, all of the definitions refer only to natural phenomena, rather than to any arbitrary physical object like "the Earth" or "the year 1900" or "Thomas Jefferson's pet kilogram."

The second is defined by the frequency of radiation emitted by a particular atomic transition in cesium.  What you do is to build (or buy) a cesium atomic clock, then you know how long a second is.

Now that you have a good clock, you can use light rays to measure distances.  Put a light source at one end of your distance, and put a mirror at the other end.  If the round-trip time for your light pulse is two seconds, then your source and your mirror are $3\times 10^8$ meters apart.

Note that I'm glossing over some implementation details. For example, $10^8$ meters is an inconveniently large distance for most ([but not all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment)) laboratories.

> so I am defining meter with the use speed of light and at the same time, I am defining the speed of light (speed in general too) with the use of meter

We are doing only the first of these things.  First you define the second, then you combine the second with speed of light to get the meter.

Comment: "rather than to any arbitrary physical object" -- if there's anyone out there with even the quietest whisper of "but why" going through their brain, I highly recommend finding a history of SI units and watching or reading it.  Not only does it answer the "but why", but it's one long tale of cutting-edge science.

Answer (score 3):

> so I am defining meter with the use speed of light and at the same time, I am defining the speed of light (speed in general too) with the use of meter

Nope.

You're defining the speed of light as an arbitrary constant.  Then you're *finding* the meter using the second (and finding the second with the help of some nearby cesium-133 atoms).

At no point are you attempting to re-derive the speed of light -- in the current SI system, the speed of light is axiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make physical assumptions to define units. If you base your definition of the meter on a bar of metal (as the SI used to), you are assuming that you can compare it to another bar of metal, and and then compare other things to that reproducibly after moving it around.

Here, the current SI definition of time is based on the ground-state hyperfine transition frequency of the cesium 133 atom. How do we know this is a clock? Various experiments have compared it to other clocks, particularly planetary orbits, and found it reproducible. In these comparisons, one accumulates enough data to quantitatively assess *how* reproducible each sort of clock is, not only with each other but with respect to the abstract physical time they measure in common. Cesium is a better clock than orbits, so that's what we use. But, to keep historical consistency, we use 9192631770 "ticks" of a cesium clock as a second. This is an arbitrary choice.

There's a whole history of such arbitrary choices going back to when time was measured by sundials. Remember that you have to make physical assumptions to define a unit. The choices were driven by increases in knowledge of physics. These caused us to judge that the revised choices better captured what we mean by "time".

Now, what about space? Remember that you have to make physical assumptions to define a unit. Until the early 20th century, we thought of space as a separate thing from time. But experiments have verified Einsteins's relativity, and Minkowski's geometric interpretation of it connects time to space. Thus, we have adjusted our physical assumptions: we assume that space and time are, for standardization purposes, the same physical thing. They've merely been measured by different technologies, historically.

By arbitrarily defining the speed of light, the SI now bases both the meter and the second on the same technology, the cesium clock. This makes the meter a more reproducible standard than previous definitions. The speed of light no longer depends on the separate choices of a standard length and a standard clock. This more reproducibly captures distance measurement based on current physical assumptions than older standards did.

Answer (score 0):

Light travels a specific distance in one second. Divide that distance into 299 792 458 equal parts. The length of each of those parts is defined as one meter. There's nothing circular about it. We have defined the meter without referencing $\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$, and we can now say that $1\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}=\frac{1\mathrm m}{1\mathrm s}$.

Alternatively, we can define the unit of one Lazovsky as $\frac{1}{ 299~792~458 }$ of the speed of light, and abbreviate it using $\mathrm L$. No reference to the meter needed. And then we can say that a meter is $1\mathrm m=1\mathrm L\cdot1\mathrm s$. And then note that once the meter is established this way, the Lazovsky can also be written as $\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s}$.

Both ways work and are consistent on their own. Choose which one you like more. But just because both ways can be used, doesn't mean that the whole thing is circular. Either way we start by fixing some specific unit, without a need to reference the other unit.

Answer (score 0):

> so I am defining meter with the use speed of light and at the same time, I am defining the speed of light (speed in general too) with the use of meter.

Yes. That is exactly right. And, those are useful definitions because the speed of light is, as far as we know, an absolute constant.

If we had some independent way of defining the length of one meter, (e.g., we could define it as the distance between two scratches on a certain bar of platinum-irridium alloy that we kept in a vault in Paris) then we could use that known length, and the fact of the constancy of the speed of light, to specify the duration of one second.

Or, if we had some independent way of defining the duration of one second (e.g., by counting the oscillations of radiation emitted by a certain excitation of cesium atoms) then we could do the opposite—use that information and the constancy of the speed of light to specify the length of one meter.

It turns out, that our best independent means of defining one second is several orders of magnitude more precise than our best independent means of defining the meter, so for official purposes, we let the meter have the dependent definition.

Comment: FWIW, from 1960 to 1983, the metre was defined in terms of the krypton-86 orange emission wavelength. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_metre#Krypton_standard